# Getting a random venue using actionscript with no repeat

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, random, random-access

Hi users of stack overflow I am currently struggling with randomizing my data via as3 and xml.

I can load in the xml fine and generate a random venue however when I click on the random button I have created, the same node is shown twice! Basically I just want to randomly select data with **no repeat** of the previous venue if this makes sense.

My xml:

```
<gallery>
<venue>
        <name>1</name>
        <description>1</description>
        <picture>images/1.jpg</picture>
        <thumb>thumbs/1.jpg</thumb>
        <address>1</address>
        <website>http://1.co.uk</website>
</venue>

<venue>
        <name>2</name>
        <description>2</description>
        <picture>images/2.jpg</picture>
        <thumb>thumbs/2.jpg</thumb>
        <address>2</address>
        <website>http://2.co.uk</website>
</venue>

<venue>
        <name>3</name>
        <description>3</description>
        <picture>images/3.jpg</picture>
        <thumb>thumbs/3.jpg</thumb>
        <address>3</address>
        <website>http://3.co.uk</website>
</venue>
</gallery>
```

My current code:

```
var xml:XML = <venues>
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/>
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/> 
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/>
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/>
</venues>;

var Gallerylist:XMLList = new XMLList(xml.venue);

function RandomGallery(e:Event)
{
    var rand:int = Gallerylist.length() * Math.random();
    myTextBoxTitle.text = myXML.venue.name[rand]
    myTextBoxDes.text = myXML.venue.description[rand]
    myTextBoxAddress.text = myXML.venue.address[rand]
    myTextBoxWeb.text = myXML.venue.website[rand]
    myVenueImage.source = myXML.venue.picture[rand]
}
randomBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, RandomGallery);
```

Comment: you need to store the name of the last selected venue to compare with the newly created venue, if they match, drop it and re-create

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with Action Script, but you might need to 'slice' elements from 'Gallerylist' as they get selected.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post links to code. Instead copy and paste the code to this page. Each question needs to be self-containing, without requiring users to go to another site (which might disappear at some point in time). I've edited your question and did it for you because I'm a nice guy :-)

Comment: @John if you are still stuck on this, I answered the same question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630707/getting-random-data-from-xml-using-as3-with-no-repeat/13630962#13630962)  It ensures that you get each venue once and they all get returned randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with all the names of the venues.  You can do this programmatically if the data set gets too large or just start out with hard coded values for your example to get it to work.  When you click the random button, pop the name off and use it to pick the next one.  This will avoid having to check to see which ones have already been used and you just have to pick from the ones remaining in the array that haven't been viewed.  When the user selects the last one and the array is empty, reinitialize it and continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to shuffle directly your xml to avoid making a new copy of the name you can use a shuffle function like the [FicherYates](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) to shuffle in place your data.

You can make an all in one function that will pickup each time it is clicked a new venue and when the end is reached restart over.

here an example of function that will pick a random element each time it responds to the click event:

```
var xml:XML = <venues>
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/>
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/> 
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/>
<venue name="" description="" address="" website="" picture=""/>
</venues>;


var fnShuffle:Function = function(xl:XMLList):Function {
 var len:int=xl.length();
 var lastUsedIndex:int;

 return function(e:MouseEvent):void{
   var i:int;

   if (len<=0) {
     // restart over since you have reached the end of the list
     len = xl.length();
     i = int(Math.random() * (len--));

     // in case of a new round you don't want to redisplay the last one again
     if (i == lastUsedIndex) i = len; 
   } else {
     i = int(Math.random() * (len--));
   }

   var myRandomVenue:XML = xl[i];
   var tmp:XML = xl[len];
   xl[i] = tmp;
   xl[len] = myRandomVenue;
   lastUsedIndex = len;

   // here do what you want with your randow venue
   trace(myRandomVenue);
 }
}

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fnShuffle(xml.venue));
```

You can see it in live at wonderfl each time you click on the TextArea : 
http://wonderfl.net/c/aQ1D

Comment: Patrick I have implemented your code however I am not getting any output. Using trace and dynamic text box! any ideas?? already loaded XML etc.... http://pastebin.com/8TfjhH6H

Sorry about linking to another site I can never get the code to display correctly! Sorry  Wouter van Nifterick :)

Comment: @John In the code myRandomVenue is the XML node you want to use , and name is an attributte not a node so it should be accessed with @ :
`myTextBoxTitle.text = myRandomVenue.@name`;

Comment: That is really weird because im still not getting an output! my full code is here just in case I am loading in the XML incorrectly!  http://pastebin.com/tes7edr2

Comment: all I have on stage is a button called randomBTN and a text box called myTextBoxTitle!

Comment: @john Well, in the code you paste you miss all in and out of loading the XML file, you have to add event listener to wait until the file is loaded and then you will be able to work with it. I suggest you to look how to load an XML file in as3.