# Getting random data from XML using AS3 with no repeat

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, random

I am still struggling loading in random data from an XML file using Actionscript 3.0 with no repeat of the previous venue.

Basically when I click a button on stage I want a random venue from my xml to display in dynamic text boxes on stage. My **XML** is located here http://pastebin.com/0qMMkfCs

It would be better to access the data directly without creating an array!

Surely someone knows how to do this correctly. Thankyou :)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531375/getting-a-random-venue-using-actionscript-with-no-repeat

Comment: no its just a personal project that I am trying to create at the moment, along with a website!

Comment: But the link I added had the same problem and used the same xml

Comment: yes I am using the same XML as in the link so I can then adapt the code to my XML!

Comment: @Gone3d LOL I think you are right.  And now that I see the other questions about this... it goes deeper than my answer would go. David.. look at that other question he linked to. It isn't the final solution I don't think (since it only ensures that the current selection isn't the same as the one previous... but doesn't ensure that all eventually come up randomly)... but it will get you headed in the right direction.  Funny... where was stack when I was in school?!?

Comment: LOL it is merely a coincidence that I am asking the same question. I am only asking the same question because that link didn't provide me with the answers I was looking for!

Comment: OK.. I'll hook ya up... hang on I'll edit my answer for ya

Comment: ok... updated to be random and only return each venue once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this edit will show how to ensure they all come up once randomly:

```
private var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
private var myLoadedXML:XML;
private var venues:XMLList;

public function getAnotherRandomVenue():XML{
    if(venues.length() > 0){
        var random:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (venues.length()-1));
        var thisRandomVenue:XML = new XML(venues[random]);
        delete venues[random];
        return thisRandomVenue;
    }
    return null;
}

public function loadItUP():void{
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoaded);
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://path.to.venuesXML.xml"));
}

private function onXMLLoaded(e:Event):void {
    myLoadedXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    venues = myLoadedXML.venue;
    // you are now ready at this point to start calling getAnotherRandomVenue()
}
```

Now calling getAnotherRandomVenue will return you a single Venue XML object. You can now either a) call this method repeatedly until it returns null (all items have been randomly returned) or b) look at venues.length() before you call it.

EDIT: merged the code to clearly when things get loaded and called.

Comment: You should consider adding some explanation to this.

Comment: @Jason Reeves. Thankyou Jason for your edit after implementing your code I keep receiving this error. 1119: Access of possibly undefined property venue through a reference with static type flash.net:URLLoader. any ideas? :)

Comment: gonna change one more thing that might mix you up  here

Comment: @Jason Reeves Getting this now #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. LOL im just rubbish at this!

Comment: look at it now... i merged it all for you

Comment: @Jason Reeves Sorry if im being dumb but how would I trace out a specific node to a text box?

Comment: using trace(getAnotherRandomVenue); but no output!

Comment: var thisVenue:XML = getAnotherRandomVenue();  myLabel.text = thisVenue.name (or thisVenue.description) and your "no output" is because need trace(getAnotherRandomVenue())

Comment: @ Jason Reeves Im still not receiving any output via trace or via a text box! no errors either :( you may want to create a new flash doc just to test this unless its just me. Most probably lol

Comment: I did and it worked as expected... trace(getAnotherRandomVenue().toString());
    trace(getAnotherRandomVenue().toString());
    trace(getAnotherRandomVenue().toString());

Comment: @Jason Reeves Would it be possible to edit your answer again to include the trace etc so I can see that I am doing this correctly. You deserve a medal for this!

Comment: Mark this answer as correct... then give me your yahoo or Skype id since you don't have enough rep to chat on stack and the comments aren't for this kinda discussion... I'll be glad to help you fix whatever you are doing wrong.

Comment: @JasonReeves my skype id is david.states93